# How can I Init a Class with a Web Service Call in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have a drug class which I would like to init by passing in a upc: Int. Inside the init I'd like to make a web service call, and populate the values in the class with the returned JSON (NSDictionary).

I have a start, but not a finish. I'm getting errors everywhere and can't seem to figure out how to best accomplish this. Maybe I'm going about this the whole wrong way. Could someone help?

Here's the code ..

```
init(upc: Int) {
    let apiKey = "xx"
    let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://something.com/\(apiKey)/")
    let getDrugByUpcURL = NSURL(string: "\(upc).json", relativeToURL: baseURL)

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let usernamePasswordString = "user:pass"
    let usernamePasswordData = usernamePasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64EncodedCredential = usernamePasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": authString]

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(getDrugByUpcURL!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
            println(dataObject)
            let drugDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
            println(drugDictionary["din"])

            drug_id = drugDictionary["drug_id"] as Int
            din = drugDictionary["din"] as String
            packsize = drugDictionary["packsize"] as Double
            brand = drugDictionary["brand"] as String
            //generic = drugDictionary["generic"] as String
            strength = drugDictionary["strength"] as String
            form = drugDictionary["form"] as String
            upc = drugDictionary["upc"] as String
            //priceGroup = drugDictionary["price_group"] as String
            //manufacturer = drugDictionary["manufacturer"] as String
            onHandQuantity = drugDictionary["onhand"] as Double
            //vendorCost = drugDictionary["vendor_cost"] as Double
            //basePrice = drugDictionary["base_price"] as Double
            //discount = drugDictionary["discount"] as Double
            //price = drugDictionary["price"] as Double
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    })

    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

An error I'm getting is on all property assignment lines: Cannot assign to 'drug_id' in 'self'.

Comment: Where and how is drug_id defined/created?

Comment: All of those are properties of the class, var drug_id: Int

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are accessing those instance variables from a closure, the completion handler of `downloadTaskWithURL:`.

This is easily fixed by prefixing the variables with `self.`. So `drug_id` becomes `self.drug_id`.

Note however that what you are doing in the above code is probably a bad idea. Or at least a very uncommon design: I don't think it is a good idea to do asynchronous network requests in your class' initializer.

Since the call to `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` is asynchronous, your init() will return immediately with uninitialized data and then at some unspecified moment in time your class will be fully populated with the result from the web service call. You don't know what that moment in time is though, so you really have no good way of knowing when your instance is ready.

This is most likely not what you had in mind.

Comment: Well that's the problem too, I'm not sure this is the best way to do this, it's a starting point, do you have a better idea of how to accomplish this task?

Comment: Oh, and self. isn't the problem, as you can see from the error output, it's saying I cannot assign drug_id in self. I've tried adding self, didn't work.

Comment: Then show more code. Like more of your class and properties.